# After using set_code_hash to upgrade contract, when decode on the new Storage，why there wont has error of "Not enough data to fill buffer"

Tags: ink, scale-codec, upgrade

I'm learning how to upgrade ink! contract，and have some question：

Eg：old `contractA`, storage define is

```
#[ink(storage)
pub struct MyContract {
    a: u32,
}
```

new `contractB`，storage define is

```
#[ink(storage)
pub struct MyContract {
    a: u32,
    b: String,
}
```

Suppose now `contractA` rootKey(contract) value is `0x01`，use `set_code_hash` to upgrade `contractA` to `contractB`

Then call `contractA`，when message call，will first invoke `get_contract_storage` to get rootKey(contract) value(is `0x01`)，use this value to decode new contract storage struct(`contractB` storage), maybe get error

```
Error { cause: None, desc: "Not enough data to fill buffer" }), desc: "Could not decode `MyContract::b`" }
```

`MessageDecoder` define as

```
impl ::ink::reflect::ExecuteDispatchable for __ink_MessageDecoder {
        #[allow(clippy::nonminimal_bool, clippy::let_unit_value)]
        fn execute_dispatchable(
            self,
        ) -> ::core::result::Result<(), ::ink::reflect::DispatchError> {
            let key = <Flipper as ::ink::storage::traits::StorageKey>::KEY;
            let mut contract: ::core::mem::ManuallyDrop<Flipper> = ::core::mem::ManuallyDrop::new(
                match ::ink::env::get_contract_storage(&key) { // get contract value and decode
                    ::core::result::Result::Ok(
                        ::core::option::Option::Some(value),
                    ) => value,
                    ::core::result::Result::Ok(::core::option::Option::None) => {
                        ::core::panicking::panic_fmt(
                            format_args!("storage entry was empty"),
                        );
                    }
                    ::core::result::Result::Err(_) => {
                        ::core::panicking::panic_fmt(
                            format_args!("could not properly decode storage entry"),
                        );
                    }
                },
            );
```

So why there wont has *scale::Decode* error，how `set_code_hash` works to achieve **Storage Compatibility**，is there some step I've missed?